# "Invalid SQL statement" error when trying to execute SQL Server stored procedure from Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, stored-procedures

I'm operating on a virtual machine where my SQL server and MS Access sit. I set up an ODBC connection from Access to SQL and linked a few tables. I can perform the usual operations on these tables (select/update etc.).

BUT, I'm unable to run a stored procedure for some weird reason! The procedure runs perfectly on SSMS but not when I call it from Access VBA. Following is the code I'm using to execute the proc (I need to pass 3 parameters as well, but I've excluded that from the code below for simplicity):

```
With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qPass")
  .SQL = "exec [HS].[spGetXMLExtract]"
  .Execute
End With
```

The error returned by MS Access is

> Invalid SQL statement: expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'.

Don't know if this is happening because:
1. I've got these applications on a VM; and/or
2. I need to somehow link the stored procedure to MS Access just like I did for the tables (perhaps this can't be done).

I guess there are convoluted methods I 'might' be able to adopt but I don't want to. Example:

**1.** Create a table in SQL with columns that store the parameters; Write an `AFTER UPDATE` Trigger on that table which executes my stored procedure; Fire an 'Update' query from MS Access that would update the parameters in that table and a SQL trigger then gets fired. OR;

**2.** Eliminate the stored procedure from the equation completely and execute it's individual statements (select/update/insert etc.) through a Sub in MS Access. Don't know if this would cause problems with creating temp tables though.

Can someone please advise on this, this is a real blocker!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This should work. Are you sure "qPass" is a Pass-Through query with the correct connection string, and `ReturnsRecords` = False ? -- What if you run that query manually?

Comment: sounds like you diid not create the query qPass as a pass-though. When using the SQL designer, make sure you click on (select) the pass-through option. ONce done your code should work fine.

Comment: Thanks guys. I don't know why it's not working, the query seems to be a Pass Through to me. For now I've used a trigger to save time since I need to meet a deadline. But I'll into this further!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will receive that error message if the QueryDef does not have a valid `"ODBC;..."` connection string as its `.Connect` property. That is how Access identifies the QueryDef as a pass-through query.

If you already have an ODBC linked table defined, you can use its `.Connect` property value for the `.Connect` property of the QueryDef, like so:

```vbs
Dim cdb As DAO.Database
Set cdb = CurrentDb
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set qdf = cdb.CreateQueryDef("")
qdf.Connect = cdb.TableDefs("dbo_table1").Connect  ' grab .Connect string from linked table
qdf.sql = "exec [HS].[spGetXMLExtract]"
qdf.ReturnsRecords = False
qdf.Execute
```

... or, if the stored procedure does in fact return a result set:

```vbs
Dim cdb As DAO.Database
Set cdb = CurrentDb
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set qdf = cdb.CreateQueryDef("")
qdf.Connect = cdb.TableDefs("dbo_table1").Connect  ' grab .Connect string from linked table
qdf.sql = "exec [HS].[spGetXMLExtract]"
qdf.ReturnsRecords = True
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)
Do Until rst.EOF
    ' do stuff
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
rst.Close
```

Comment: Thanks @GordThompson. I don't know why it's not working even after this. For now I've used a trigger to save time since I need to meet a deadline. But I'll into this further!

Answer (score 2):

I do not have access right now to MS-Access, but it seems to me that the good syntax is:

```
`strSQL = "exec [HS].[spGetXMLExtract]"
 With CurrentDb.QueryDefs(strSQL)
'Fill parameters
 .Parameters(0) = My first param
 .Parameters(1) = My 2nd param
 .Parameters(2) = My last param
'Execute the query
 .Execute
End With `
```

I hope that will help !

Comment: Thanks @Mohamad. I don't know why it's not working, I seem to have a similar syntax to yours. For now I've used a trigger to save time since I need to meet a deadline. But I'll into this further and provide an update on this thread!

Comment: Sorry, if it does not work!
What is your mode of access to SQL Server: ADO, OLEDB, ...
I advise you to take a look at this link:
Http://accessexperts.com/blog/2011/07/29/sql-server-stored-procedure-guide-for-microsoft-access-part-1/.
Hope this can help ..

Comment: `I made a mistake in writing` _What is your mode of access to SQL Server: ADO, OLEDB,_ ... *Because* ADO = OLEDB, I should write DOA, OLEDB, etc ...